# Jquery - Add custom validation rules to dynamically generated dropdownlist in dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am creating some dynamic dropdownlists in jquery dialog, and i want to validate them with the rule: Only one of the dropdown should be selected.

I am very new to Jquery and found while googling & on SO that this is possible via Jquery validate plugin.

So I downloaded the Jquery validate plugin and loaded it on page but I am not able to correct validation code.

So far I have created the dialog & populated the dynamic controls, but not sure how to add dynamic rule.

Any suggestions on this would be helpful.

Thanks

**Populate dynamic control:**

```
if (conflictOccured) {
            for (a = 0; a < selectedOoOptions.length; a++) {                                         
                    if (selectedOoOptions[a].OptionId == selectedOptionId) {
                        var item = populateListItem(selectedOptionId, selectedOoOptions[a].Description, paidById, "OoPaidByOption2");                                                      
                        break;
                    }                  
            }
            $("#OptionsUI").empty();
            $.each(OutputArray, function (obj, i) {
                $('#OptionsUI').append(i);
            });

            OutputArray = [];
            initialiseDialog();
            $("#optionsDialog").dialog("open");
            return false;
        }


function populateListItem(optionId, description, paidById, optionName) {
            return '<li>' +
                        '<span>' +
                            '<input type="hidden" id="OptionsId" value="' + optionId + '" /> </span>' +
                            '<span>' + description + '</span>' +
                        '</span><select class="select" id="OptionPaidbyList" name="'+ optionName +'">' +
                            '<option value="0">Select</option>' +
                            '<option value="1">On Rent</option>' +
                            '<option value="2">Paid</option>' +
                            '</select>' +
                    '</li>';
        }
```

**Dialog DIV**

```
 <div id="optionsDialog" title="Please select">
    <form id="OptionsDialogForm">
        <div id="OoOptions_div">
            <p id="RuleTitle"></p>    
            <ul id="ooOptionsUI">           
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="ValidationError_div"></div>
    </form>       
</div>
```

**Initialise Dialog**

```
 function initialiseDialog() {        
        var $this = this;
        $("#optionsDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 650,
            dialogClass: "no-close",
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $('#OptionsDialogForm').validate({  // initialize the plugin
                    // your other rules or options,                
                    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {                          
                        error.appendTo($('#ValidationError_div'))

                    }
                });

                $('[name^="OoPaidByOption"]').each(function () { // all names starting with 'OoPaidByOption'
                    $(this).rules('add', {        // attach same rules to each of these fields
                        required: {
                            depends: function (element) {
                                return $(this).closest('option:selected').val() != 0
                            }
                        },
                        messages: {
                            required: "Please select a option"
                        }
                    });
                    alert("rules applied");
                });
            },
            buttons: {
                OK: function (event, ui) {                       
                    if ($("#OptionsDialogForm").valid()) {
                        resolveConflict()
                    }
                },
                Cancel: function (event, ui) {
                    closeDialog();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**Validation Rule: (This code is now removed)**

```
 $('#ooOptionsUI > li').each(function(){
            $(this).rules("add", {
                option1: {
                    required: {
                        depends: function (element) {
                            return $('#OoPaidByOption1 option:selected').val() != 0
                        }
                    }
                },
                option2: {
                    required: {
                        depends: function (element) {
                            return $('#OoPaidByOption2 option:selected').val() != 0;
                        }
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    option1: "Please select only one option",
                    option2: "Please select only one option"
                },
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    error.appendTo($('#OoValidationError_div'))
                }
            });
        });
```

**HTML Produced:**

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all no-close ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-dialog-buttons" tabindex="-1" style="outline: 0px; z-index: 1002; position: absolute; height: auto; width: 650px; top: 348.5px; left: 302px; display: block;" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1">
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"><span id="ui-id-1" class="ui-dialog-title">Please select</span><a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a></div>
<div id="optionsDialog" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0" style="width: auto; min-height: 1px; height: auto;">
    <form id="OptionsDialogForm" novalidate="novalidate">
        <div id="OoOptions_div">
            <p id="RuleTitle"></p>
            <ul id="ooOptionsUI">
                <li><span>
                    <input type="hidden" id="OptionsId" value="1"></span><span>17" alloy wheels</span>
                    <select class="select valid" id="OptionPaidbyList" name="OoPaidByOption1" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
                        <option value="0">Select</option>
                        <option value="1">Rental</option>
                        <option value="2">Paid</option>
                    </select></li>
                <li><span>
                    <input type="hidden" id="Hidden1" value="2">
                </span><span>18" alloy wheels </span>
                    <select class="select" id="Select1" name="OoPaidByOption2" aria-required="true">
                        <option value="0">Select</option>
                        <option value="1"> Rental</option>
                        <option value="2">Paid</option>
                    </select></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="ValidationError_div"></div>
    </form>
</div>   
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
    <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
        <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">OK</span></button>
        <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to show the rendered HTML after the new elements are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start by explaining why the following is totally wrong...

```
 $('#ooOptionsUI > li').each(function(){
     $(this).rules("add", {
        option1: {
            ....
        },
        option2: {
            ....
        },
        messages: {
            ....
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            ....
        }
    });
});
```

1. Your selector, `$('#ooOptionsUI > li')`, is targeting an `li` element.  The `.rules()` method can only be attached to `input`, `textarea` or `select` elements, not an `li` element.
2. Your `.rules()` method contains a list of field names, `option1` and `option2`.  Since the `.rules()` method is already attached to a field, it can only contain a list of rules pertaining to that field and the `messages` option; nothing else.  (It does not make any sense to attach the `.rules()` method to a field and then put more fields inside of it.)
3. Your `.rules()` method contains the `errorPlacement` option.  The `.rules()` method can only contain a list of rules and the `messages` option; nothing else.  The `errorPlacement` option can ***only*** be placed inside of the [`.validate()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) or [`.setDefaults()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/) methods.

---

Since you have a `depends` option that is very specifically written for one field, you'll have to use the `.rules()` method separately on each.

It should look more like this...

```
$('#yourForm').validate({  // initialize the plugin
    // your other rules or options,
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.appendTo($('#OoValidationError_div'))
    }
});

$('[name="myField_1"]').rules('add', {  // attach rules to field 1
    required: {
        depends: function (element) {
            return $('#OoPaidByOption1 option:selected').val() != 0
        }
    },
    messages: {
        required: "Please select only one option"
    }
});

$('[name="myField_2"]').rules('add', {  // attach rules to field 2
    required: {
        depends: function (element) {
            return $('#OoPaidByOption2 option:selected').val() != 0
        }
    },
    messages: {
        required: "Please select only one option"
    }
});
```

---

I cannot see your rendered HTML, but there might be a way for you to combine everything.  That's only if there's a more generic way for you to write the `depends` function.

This is only a generic suggestion...

```
$('[name^="myField"]').each(function() { // all names starting with 'myField'
    $(this).rules('add', {        // attach same rules to each of these fields
        required: {
            depends: function (element) {
                return $(this).closest('option:selected').val() != 0
            }
        },
        messages: {
            required: "Please select only one option"
        }
    });
});
```

---

Ok, now I see why you think you need the `depends` option.  That's not how the `depends` option was meant to work, and in this case, it's not needed.

Change your HTML so that your `select` looks like this.  Note that first `option` contains a `value=""`.

```
<select class="select valid" id="OptionPaidbyList" name="OoPaidByOption1" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Rental</option>
    <option value="2">Paid</option>
</select>
```

Then your `.rules()` method can simply be this...

```
$('[name^="myField"]').each(function() { // all names starting with 'myField'
    $(this).rules('add', {        // attach same rules to each of these fields
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "Please select only one option"
        }
    });
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/mL6x8enc/**

Comment: Many Thanks for helping me on this. 
I really liked your generic solution, but I am not able to make it work. 
Its not throwing any errors but the validation is not working.
I think the rule is not getting applied to the dialog form, 
i tried putting this code in document.ready() function, On-click of Ok button on Dialog, Open tag in initialise dialog 
but nothing seems to be working.
Can you please help me with - why this rules it not getting applied. 
 I have edited my question to include your code and Dialog HTML.

Comment: @Vin05, The "generic" answer was not expected to work exactly as I wrote it... just a suggestion that you would need to figure out your own DOM traversal technique that works for you.  Anyway, see the edits on my answer as `depends` is not how you validate a `select` element.

Comment: Thanks Sparky, the reason I was using depend is because only one of the option(one dropdown) should be selected, if user select both or none than the validation will fail.

Comment: @Vin05, you never previously said that your requirement is to only have one selected out of two and fail when both are selected, so how would you expect anyone to know that?  No, that also cannot be done with a `depends`, since `required:false` simply means that the item is optional, not prohibited.  You would need to write a custom rule using [the `addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).  Simply write your own rule and apply it to the dynamic elements as I've shown in my answer.  Otherwise, I've fully answered your question as you've presented it above.